# Is there any way to delay a Chrome response payload using Puppeteer or Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

Below is the code I am using to delay a *request* in the Chrome browser using the [PuppeteerSharp](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/) library.

```
        public static void HandleRequestIntercepted(object sender, RequestEventArgs args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                await args.Request.ContinueAsync();
            });
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Browser b = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions()
                {
                    ExecutablePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
                    DefaultViewport = null,
                    Headless = false
                });

                Page[] pages = await b.PagesAsync();
                Page page = pages[0];


                CDPSession cdpSession = await page.Target.CreateCDPSessionAsync();
                JObject obj = await cdpSession.SendAsync("Network.enable");
                await page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);

                // Subscribe to requests
                page.Request += HandleRequestIntercepted;
            }
        }
```

However, is it possible to similarly delay a *response*? Specifically, I would like Chrome to delay the response payload for X amount of time.

Comment: What's your goal there?

Comment: The goal is feature parity with a different product :) But in reality the goal is simulating a slow server.

Comment: Maybe you can emulate a network condition? https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v7.0.0/docs/api.md#pageemulatenetworkconditionsnetworkconditions

Comment: @hardkoded Perhaps the strategy should be to intercept the request as the "Response" stage, per this PR: https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/pull/1184

Comment: ah it was you :p that could also help

Comment: @hardkoded Sorry if this is a silly question, but can PuppeteerSharp push forward with the functionality in the above PR and not wait for Puppeteer? (I find myself trying to implement this with `SendAsync("Fetch.enable", new FetchEnableRequest {...})` and copy/pasting some of the objects from this PR into my code.)

Comment: The goal of PuppeteerSharp is to be a port, that brings benefits and also a cost. My next goal would try to be to try to implement it in puppeteer and see if they accept it. If they don't use it, they might remove it freely and we would be lost.

Comment: @hardkoded Just in case you are interested, I posted an answer below. Unfortunately intercepting the response seems intermittent (see the screenshots) - do you know why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to introduce a response delay with the following code:

```
        public static CDPSession _cdpSessionResponse;

        public static void CdpSessionMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.MessageID == "Fetch.requestPaused")
            {
                Task.Run(async () => 
                {
                    await Task.Delay(3000); // Wait 3 seconds
                    await _cdpSessionResponse.SendAsync("Fetch.continueRequest",
                        new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            { "requestId", args.MessageData.ToObject<FetchRequestPausedResponse>().RequestId }
                        });
                });
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Browser b = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions()
                {
                    ExecutablePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
                    DefaultViewport = null,
                    Headless = false
                });

                Page[] pages = await b.PagesAsync();
                Page page = pages[0];

               

                // Set up RESPONSE interception using PuppeteerSharp
                
                _cdpSessionResponse = await page.Target.CreateCDPSessionAsync();

                JObject response = await _cdpSessionResponse.SendAsync("Fetch.enable",
                    new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {
                            "patterns", new Dictionary<string, object>[]
                            {
                                new Dictionary<string, object>
                                {
                                    { "requestStage", "Response" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                _cdpSessionResponse.MessageReceived += CdpSessionMessageReceived;
            }
        }

        internal class FetchRequestPausedResponse
        {
            public string RequestId { get; set; }

            public string NetworkId { get; set; }
        }
```

However, this is puzzling because here is what I see in the Chrome DevTools Network tab -- not all responses were delayed with a long blue line:
[image]

For comparison, if I change the line `{ "requestStage", "Response" }` to `{ "requestStage", "Request" }`, I see that all the requests were delayed with a long transparent line (queuing time):
[image]

I'm not sure why there is this difference - perhaps this is internal to Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Comment: I played with your code a little bit. It seems you were having some fun. :) There are many requests there that return 204 (no content) and there are others where even if I set a long long delay, the request is being drawn as a short request. But there weren't that short. All in all it seems that it's something in that rendering.

Comment: If you are using a local browser I would add `await page.SetCacheEnabledAsync(false);`